# BQ E5 phone touch screen does not respond

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen

BQ Aquaris E5 running ubuntu touch. My phone worked fine until this morning. But now, the screen does not respond to touch. I tried restarting it, that didn't help either. The volume and the power buttons work fine. Since the phone is locked, I can't even connect it to PC.

Comment: maybe it's a hardware problem?

Comment: Thanks. It could be. The phone responds during fastboot, though. I have tried factory reset, except that now I'm practically locked out of the phone and it can't even update automatically on wi-fi, since that would require me to work through the screen, which does not respond.  Is there a way to reload the complete software bypassing screen use (just curious)?

Comment: @Abhishek screen responds in fastboot? is it a touchscreen bootloader?

Comment: No, the touchscreen doesn't respond in fastboot. I meant the phone updates and I could "factory reset" it.

Comment: I might have to go for an android phone now, or use android on the BQ E5. Whatever happens first. That, unfortunately, would be a heartbreak.